# Oracle sql trigger on insert/update to calculate 2 values and update a third value

Tags: triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to make a trigger that will update the row by calculating 2 values and update the third one:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    Cust_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Dates TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
    Quantity dec(7,2) NOT NULL,
    Price_per_item dec(7,2) NOT NULL,
    Total_price dec(7,2)
);
```

I have done this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_after_insert AFTER INSERT 
ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customers
    SET 
    DATES = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Total_price = Quantity * Price_per_item;
END;
```

I get some kind of errors that I try to view and edit table at the same time.

I've also tried this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE cust_Seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_trig BEFORE INSERT ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT cust_Seq.nextval INTO :new.Fuel_ID FROM dual;
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO :new.DATES FROM dual;
  SELECT Quantity * Price_per_item INTO :new.Total_price FROM dual;
END;
/
```

I would prefer the second option and I will need something if an UPDATE will occur as well.

Comment: What errors do you get? "Some kind of errors" doesn't help with debugging the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is in the right direction, but it needs some tweaking to handle the `Total_price` calculation and to handle `update`s too:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE cust_Seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cust_trig BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    SELECT cust_Seq.nextval INTO :new.Fuel_ID FROM dual;
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO :new.DATES FROM dual;
  END IF;
  :new.Total_price :=  :new.Quantity * :new.Price_per_item;
END;
/
```

Comment: It's perfect, just a small typo "END ID" need's to be "END IF", Thank you!

Comment: @Attila thanks for noticing the `END ID` typo - fixed.